# cygwin64 :: ./configure returns "configure: exit 77"

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, cygwin, configure

I've installed `Cygwin64` and I now would like to install [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).

So I downloaded it, decompressed the file, but when I run `./configure` it says:

```
$ ./configure
Configuring extundelete 0.2.4
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Users/franc/Desktop/extundelete-0.2.4':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

[image]

So I open the `config.log` file and I find some error:

```
configure:2876: $? = 0
configure:2865: CC -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=CC
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-9.2.0-2.x86_64/src/gcc-9.2.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-9.2.0-2.x86_64/src/gcc-9.2.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC) 
configure:2876: $? = 0
configure:2865: CC -V >&5
CC: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
CC: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2876: $? = 1
configure:2865: CC -qversion >&5
CC: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
CC: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2876: $? = 1
configure:2896: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:2918: CC    conftest.cpp  >&5
CC: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': spawn: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:2922: $? = 1
configure:2960: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "extundelete"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "extundelete"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.2.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "extundelete 0.2.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "extundelete.sourceforge.net"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "extundelete"
| #define VERSION "0.2.4"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2965: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Users/franc/Desktop/extundelete-0.2.4':
configure:2967: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And the .log file ends up with `configure: exit 77`

Is it possible to compile files in Cygwin64?

Comment: Configuration output doesn't look like the one produced by CMake. Why do you use `cmake` tag?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, what command should I use instead? The output is longer, do you want all the >200 lines?

Comment: I don't mean that you use wrong command. I ask why do you use `cmake` tag for your question. How does this tag relate to the problem?

Comment: extundelete is a utility that can recover deleted files from an ext3 or ext4 partition. Why you install on cygwin ?

Comment: do NOT build under the Windows Home directories. The permissions inherited from `C:\Users\franc` can screw the execution permission need by the build process. Use the `/home/franc` or the `/usr/src` directories. PS: Of course it is possible to build under Cygwin 64bit; how do you think the packages were built ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build problem is likely due to permissions inherited from `C:\Users\franc` that screw the execution permission needed by the build process.
Use the `/home/franc` or the `/usr/src` directories or other similar ones.
Do **NOT** build under the Windows Home directories.

Unfortunately you can not build the program on Cygwin for another reason; see below:

In a proper directory you will have:

```
$ ./configure
Configuring extundelete 0.2.4
Writing generated files to disk
```

To avoid some scope error, you can remove the restricting invocation from the makefiles

```
$ find . -name Makefile -exec sed -e "s/-std=c99//" -i {} \;
$ find . -name Makefile -exec sed -e "s/-std=c++0x -std=c++11//" -i {} \;
```

and then build

```
$ make
make -s all-recursive
Making all in src
...
insertionops.cc: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const ext2_inode&)’:
insertionops.cc:36:36: error: ‘const struct ext2_inode’ has no member named ‘i_dir_acl’; did you mean ‘i_file_acl’?
   36 |   os << "Directory ACL: " << inode.i_dir_acl << std::endl;
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                    i_file_acl
make[2]: *** [Makefile:437: extundelete-insertionops.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:268: all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:208: all] Error 2
```

and you can not overcome the lack of extended property from the Cygwin ext2 inode structure.
As Cygwin is a Windows user mode program it can not mount a filesystem not recognized by Windows as its support of ext2 is very limited and mainly focused on just making the file system on a external disk but it can not really use it.